# Determine where FileSystemAccessRule is inherited from in C#

Tags: c#, security, acl

Is it possible in C#/.NET to determine where an inherited `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule` was actually inherited from? If so, how do I do that? I want to create an output that is like in the Windows security property, where you can see to which object an inherited ACE was attached to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to walk through the file or folder's path to find where the rule originated. Here's a crude set of functions that will print all access rules and where the originated from. You can easily modify this to create a more useful API (in other words, not just print to Console).

```
void PrintAccessRules(string path)
{   
    var security = File.GetAccessControl(path);

    var accessRules = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));


    foreach (var rule in accessRules.Cast<FileSystemAccessRule>())
    {
        if (!rule.IsInherited)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} to {2} was set on {3}.", rule.AccessControlType, rule.FileSystemRights, rule.IdentityReference, path);
            continue;
        }

        FindInheritedFrom(rule, Directory.GetParent(path).FullName);
    }
}

void FindInheritedFrom(FileSystemAccessRule rule, string path)
{
    var security = File.GetAccessControl(path);
    var accessRules = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

    var matching = accessRules.OfType<FileSystemAccessRule>()
        .FirstOrDefault(r => r.AccessControlType == rule.AccessControlType && r.FileSystemRights == rule.FileSystemRights && r.IdentityReference == rule.IdentityReference);

    if (matching != null)
    {
        if (matching.IsInherited) FindInheritedFrom(rule, Directory.GetParent(path).FullName);
        else Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} to {2} is inherited from {3}", rule.AccessControlType, rule.FileSystemRights, rule.IdentityReference, path);
    }
}
```

For example:

```
PrintAccessRules(@"C:\projects\mg\lib\repositories.config");
```

Prints the following for me:

```
Allow FullControl to SkipTyler\Mike was set on C:\projects\mg\lib\repositories.config.
Allow ReadAndExecute, Synchronize to SkipTyler\Mike is inherited from C:\projects\mg
Allow FullControl to BUILTIN\Administrators is inherited from C:\
Allow FullControl to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM is inherited from C:\
Allow ReadAndExecute, Synchronize to BUILTIN\Users is inherited from C:\
```

Comment: You do not know about any Windows API version of this, which is more efficient? I thought of that, too, but it is a rather costly algorithm if you process a lot of files.

Comment: There isn't a way in managed code. Since the managed code just uses WinAPI, I'm not sure that there's a way using a straight p/invoke to WinAPI, either.